# Create multiple postgres servers with docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I'm trying to create multiple postgres services with docker compose,
but I can't connect to the second host with the second port 5433:

```
listings-service-db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=admin
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin1234
        - POSTGRES_DB=listings
    ports: 
        - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes: 
        - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

users-service:
    build: "./users-service"
    depends_on:
        - users-service-db
    volumes:
        - ./users-service:/opt/app/  

users-service-db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=admin
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin1234
        - POSTGRES_DB=users
    ports: 
        - "5433:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes: 
        - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

i get this error

[image]

even I recover the host well

[image]

[image]

for the first service it is easily created

Comment: You seem to have included a PNG file in place of the error message.  Can you [edit] the question to include details like how your application code connects to the container and what error you get?  (Connections between containers ignore `ports:`, so if `users-service` is trying to connect to `users-service-db` it needs the standard PostgreSQL port 5432.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `users-service-db` must map the right port within the container. also, give them different volumes.

```
listings-service-db:
  volumes: 
    - database-data-listings:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

users-service-db:
  ports: 
    - "5433:5432"
  volumes: 
    - database-data-users:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

Comment: even if with the ports:
    - "5433:5432"
I had the same error :(
I can't create two servers

Comment: i think it is because you are sharing same volume with both containers. try to give them different volumes

Comment: thank you @YK1 :)
problem solved by changing the volume,
and also i had to enter the same port "5432" when creating the two servers,
even it's set to 5433 in docker-compose,
honestly I couldn't figure it out but it works :)